# File input getting consumed inside the while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm reading through a lookup file and performing a set of actions for each line in the file. However the while loop only reads the first line in the file and exits. Here's the current code that I have.

```
sql_from_lkp $lookup

function sql_from_lkp {
    lkp=$1
    while read line; do
        sql_from_columns ${line}
        echo ${line}
    done < ${lkp}
}

function sql_from_columns {
    table_name=$1
    table_column_info_file=${table_name}_columns
    line_count=`cat $table_info_file | wc -l`
    ....
}
```

By selectively commenting the code, I found that if I comment the `line_count` line, the while loop goes through every line in the file and works fine. So the input is getting consumed by the `cat` statement.

I've checked other answers and understood that `ssh` usually consumes the file inputs inside `while` loops if -n option is not used. But not sure how to fix this case. Need some help.

Comment: As an aside: you should double-quote all your variable references so as not to subject the variable values to word-splitting and globbing; also, Bash won't allow you to call functions before they're defined.

Comment: At first blush it looks like you are passing `line` to `sql_from_colums` that is expecting a `table_name` as input?

Comment: @David I basically have a table on each line. I refactored the code and removed lot of details to make the scenario easy to appear.

Comment: @Vinay : Also suggest the [\[ shell_check \]](http://shellcheck.net) tool which will help you identify petty errors pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mistyped a variable name: `$table_info_file` should be `$table_column_info_file`.

If you correct that, your problem will go away.

---

By referring to a non-extant variable - the mistyped `$table_info_file` - you're essentially executing `cat | wc -l` (no filename argument passed to `cat`) in `sql_from_columns()`, which makes `cat` read from *stdin*.

Therefore - after having read the *1st* line in the `while` loop - the `cat` command in `sql_from_columns()` consumes *the entire rest* of your input (`< ${lkp}`), which is why the `while` loop exits after the 1st iteration.

---

Generally,

- You should double-quote all your variable references so as not to subject their values to [word-splitting and globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).
- Bash won't allow you to call functions before they're defined, so as presented in your question, your code *fundamentally* couldn't work.
- While the legacy `` `...` ``  syntax for command substitutions is still supported, it has [pitfalls that can be avoided with the modern `$(...)` syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).
- A more efficient way to count lines is to pass the input file to `wc -l` via `<` rather than via `cat` and a pipeline (`wc` also accepts filename operands *directly*, but it then prints the input filename after the counts).

  - Incidentally, you probably would have caught your mistyped variable reference more easily had you done that, as Bash would have reported an `ambiguous redirect` error in the absence of a filename following `<`.

Here's a reformulation that addresses all the issues:

```
function sql_from_lkp {
    lkp=$1
    while read line; do
        sql_from_columns "${line}"
        echo "${line}"
    done < "${lkp}"
}

function sql_from_columns {
    table_name=$1
    table_column_info_file=${table_name}_columns
    line_count=$(wc -l < "$table_column_info_file")
    # ...
}

sql_from_lkp "$lookup"
```

Note that I've only added double quotes where strictly needed to make the command robust; it wouldn't hurt to add them whenever a parameter (variable) is referenced.

Comment: Can't believe that I missed that. Takes longer to find this than to write the script itself. Thanks for pointing it out and for the best practices!